# CSS custom shape with border radius

Tags: css, css-shapes

I want to create something like this via CSS.

[image]

Just want to use only CSS to create this custom shape with border radius. Any ideas please?

Comment: With only CSS? Tough job.

Comment: I'd recommend you draw this shape in illustrator and export it as SVG CODE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can overlap a few div tags and use the skew effect.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="shape shape1"></div>
    <div class="shape shape2"></div>
    <div class="shape shape3"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px;
}
.shape {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 200px;
}
.shape:after {
  border-radius: 5px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.shape1:after {
  -webkit-transform: skew(-5deg, -3deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-5deg, -3deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-5deg, -3deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-5deg, -3deg);
  transform: skew(-5deg, -3deg);    
}
.shape2:after {
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, -1deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(0deg, -1deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(0deg, -1deg);
  -o-transform: skew(0deg, -1deg);
  transform: skew(0deg, -1deg);
  top: 4px;
  left: 3px;
}
.shape3:after {
  -webkit-transform: skew(3deg, -2deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(2deg, -2deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(2deg, -2deg);
  -o-transform: skew(2deg, -2deg);
  transform: skew(2deg, -2deg);
  top: 2px;
  left: -5px;
}
.set2 {
  margin-top: 80px;
}
.set2 .shape2:after {
  background: red;
}
.set2 .shape3:after {
  background: blue;
}
```

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremyhawes/tM7B8/1/)

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look into CSS3 2D Transforms. It's possible to do similar things, but there are limitations as well. I tried to do something similar to the referenced shape :)

```
// CSS
#shape {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 200px;
    margin:30px;
}

#shape:after {
    border-radius: 5px;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: green;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-5deg, -3deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-5deg, -3deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-5deg, -3deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-5deg, -3deg);
    transform: skew(-5deg, -3deg);
}

// HTML
<div id="shape"></div>
```

Check the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tM7B8/)